# How to read binary data from socket with Apache MINA?

Tags: java, sockets, apache-mina

I know that a server sends MP3 stream after connecting to it and sending few bytes. How to read it's transmission with Apache MINA? Can you provide any examples please?

Answer (score 6):

You need a client to read data from server. If it is possible to make a TCP connection with the server you can get help from [this tutorial](http://mina.apache.org/sample-tcp-client.html) on Apache MINA TCP client

[UPDATE]
Data will be received in [ClientSessionHandler](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/xref/org/apache/mina/example/sumup/ClientSessionHandler.html)'s `messageReceived`. You can override this function according to you need. You may go through [SumUp](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/xref/org/apache/mina/example/sumup/) example to understand it fully.

[UPDATE 2]
To receive bytes in your case, you will have to update `messageReceived` of your session handler a bit. You can use [IoBuffer](http://mina.apache.org/iobuffer.html) to read byte. Something like this :

```
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) {

            if (message instanceof IoBuffer) {

                IoBuffer buffer = (IoBuffer) message;
                byte[] b = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(b);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please point, where is the binary data reading lines on that page?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to access bytes? My server does not written in Mina so I can't expect it returns any specific java class.

Comment: @SuzanCioc see the updated answer. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: So you are sure that if raw bytes are sended from third party server, then MINA wraps them into IoBuffer?

Comment: Not yet. I have used conventional sockets meanwhile. So please can you give me a link to MINA API docs or some other manuals where it is said that IoBuffer is used in my case? Or wait a bit please when I will check it.